# Delete from DataFrame if value exists

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1, 'ABC'], [2, 'ABC'], [3, 'ABCDEF'], [1, 'ABCDEF']], columns=['id', 'marker'])
```

I'm effectively trying to do this SQL statement but in Pandas.

```
delete #table
from #table a, #table b
where a.id = b.id
and a.marker = b.marker + 'DEF'
```

Which would effectively get rid of the last row in the dataframe. Any idea how I can do this?

EDIT:

To clarify on the above, lets say the data is like this:

```
   id  marker
0   1     ABC
1   2     ABC
2   3  ABCDEF
3   1  ABCDEF
4   4  ABCDEF
```

The answer should be

```
   id  marker
0   1     ABC
1   2     ABC
2   3  ABCDEF
4   4  ABCDEF
```

(1, 'ABCDEF') is omitted because (1, 'ABC') is present, which is what the SQL statement would effectively do (i.e., delete all rows where IDs are equal and marker has 'DEF' attached). If for ID X there is only 'ABCDEF' present it would keep it, but if ID Y has both 'ABC' and 'ABCDEF' it will delete the 'ABCDEF'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one solution to get what you need. I changed the dataframe a little bit, added `[2, 'ABCDEF']` to demonstrate that this code will keep `ABC` regardless if `ABCDEF` or `ABC` appears first.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1, 'ABCDEF'], [2, 'ABC'], [2, 'ABCDEF'], [3, 'ABCDEF'], [1, 'ABC']], columns=['id', 'marker'])
df
id  marker
0   1   ABCDEF
1   2   ABC
2   2   ABCDEF
3   3   ABCDEF
4   1   ABC

lst = df.values.tolist()
list_tuples = [tuple(l) for l in lst]
newdata = {}
for key,value in list_tuples:
    newdata.setdefault(key, []).append(value)
newdata = {k:sorted(v) if len(v) > 1 else v for k,v in newdata.items()}
create_dataframe = {k:v[0] for k,v in newdata.items()}

df2 = pd.DataFrame(list(create_dataframe.items()), columns=['id', 'marker'])
df2.index = range(len(df2))
df2

id  marker
0   1   ABC
1   2   ABC
2   3   ABCDEF
```

Comment: Thanks. I meant it doesn't have to be the last row. Basically I want to replicate what that sql statement would do, which would allow me to select every row where the marker is "ABC" first, if "ABC" doesn't exists I'd take "ABCDEF"

Comment: @swmfg Then in this case, in the current example you posted, you would not delete any rows because all the values in the `marker` column are either `ABC` or `ABCDEF`?

Comment: @swmfg I changed my answer based on your comment.

Comment: @swmfg Where the `id` numbers are the same  `ABC` always will appear in the `marker`first, before the `ABCDEF`? Also, will there be any values in `marker` other than `ABC` and `ABCDEF`?

Comment: Nope, can't be guaranteed that `ABC` will always appear before `ABCDEC`, but there are only `ABC` and `ABCDEF` in the marker column. I suppose I can select for all the `ABC` first then select all `ABCDEF` where ID exists in the first DF but was looking for a more elegant solution

Comment: Thanks. More verbose than what I was hoping for but it works.